# How to install a new theme of konsole in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, konsole

I have tried the method [mentioned on GitHub](https://github.com/phiggins/konsole-colors-solarized), but I don't know what would be the format of the colorscheme file.

Also, can anyone give some recommendations about nice theme of konsole?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colorscheme-files are plain-text-files.

In Kubuntu 16.04 they are stored in `~/.local/share/konsole/`

Here is something to try: https://store.kde.org/content/show.php/Monokai+konsole+colorscheme?content=154765

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how about Kubuntu 16.10?

Comment: Should be the same, have you checked this folder?

Comment: Thanks so much, I just love how simple this answer is, have a great day :)